# Question about liquidity in burn function, UniswapV2Pair.sol

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

```
// UniswapV2Pair.sol burn function
function burn(address to) external lock returns (uint amount0, uint amount1){
    // ...
    uint balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint liquidity = balanceOf[address(this)];
    // ...
}
```

address(this) refers to the address of the instance of the contract, it means that liquidity is owned by the UniswapPair instance.

Why liquidity doesn't equal balanceOf[to] (the address of LP Token receiver)？

Answer (score 0):

This is [UniswapV2Pair.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol)

```
contract UniswapV2Pair is IUniswapV2Pair, UniswapV2ERC20 {}
```

When liquidity is added by [UniswapV2Router02.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol) contract

```
 function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity) {
        (amountA, amountB) = _addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesired, amountBDesired, amountAMin, amountBMin);
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenA, msg.sender, pair, amountA);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenB, msg.sender, pair, amountB);
        liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to);
    }
```

liquidity is minted `liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to)`. this is lp token and its type is `UniswapV2ERC20`. every pair or every `UniswapV2Pair` contract has a LP token. So when you burn LP token inside `UniswapV2Pair`, you are actually burning LP token which belongs to `UniswapV2Pair` contract itself.

```
 uint liquidity = balanceOf[address(this)]
```

`address(this)` refers to the current contract address and `balanceOf` is a mapping inside `UniswapV2ERC20`.

```
mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
```

Since `UniswapV2Pair` is inheriting from `UniswapV2ERC20`, we have a direct access to `balanceOf` inside the `UniswapV2Pair` contract